# Piping the response into a variable using streams | Axios | Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, stream

I am using Axios to extract data from an API. Since there are so many records, I am trying to pipe the response into a variable. But I am not able to do it.

```
app.post("/Node", jsonparser, async (req, res) => {
var APIdata;
axios(authOptions)
    .then((response) => {
        response.data.pipe(APIdata);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        res.send(error);
    });
}
```

Where as, I am able to send the data as a response to **res** and get it displayed in the frontend. The code for it is below.

```
app.post("/Node", jsonparser, async (req, res) => {
axios(authOptions)
    .then((response) => {
        response.data.pipe(res);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        res.send(error);
    });
}
```

Could anyone please tell me how we can save the data to a variable? The data needs to be pushed to database...

Comment: There's no advantage to streaming to a variable, in the end it will all end up in memory anyway. The reason it works with `res` is because that's a writable stream (as opposed to `APIdata`, which is just a local variable).

Comment: But I need to push the data to DB after making few alterations to the structure. Is there a way I can send the data to DB without storing it inside a variable?

Comment: It depends, what data format does the API return (JSON, CSV, something else)?

Comment: It returns data in JSON format.

Comment: Then you'd need some sort of streaming JSON parser if you want to use streaming _and_ alter the data. Plus your database has to support streaming JSON into it as well, of course.

Comment: There is a separate function 'pushData()' I created to push the data into the DB. I'm passing that function as 'response.data.pipe(pushData(response.data))' using pipe. But when I try to log the data to the console, it's displaying some weird object. Not the one that I passed. I am using JSON parser as well... Would you be able to provide a sample code?

Comment: No, I can't provide sample code. Search for "streaming JSON parser" on npmjs.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
var APIdata;
axios.get(url, { responseType: "stream" }).then(response => {
const stream = response.data;

stream.on("data", chunk => {
  APIdata.push(chunk)
};

stream.on("end", () => console.log("end of stream", APIdata));
});
```

Comment: Many thanks.. This code is working but for records which are less than 1000-2000.. I have a dataset from an API where there are ~90k records and this code is not able to handle that...